# Qt: Cisco ip phone serivices Authentication URL response

Tags: c++, qt, http-headers, cisco

I wrote a program with Qt to work with cisco ip phone services. I'm using QNetworkAccessManager to post XML objects to phones and QTcpServer's socket with QTextStream to respond to authentication requests (simply writing http headers with "AUTHORIZED" to text stream).

```
QString cTime = currTime.currentDateTimeUtc().toString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    QTextStream os(socket); os << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
          "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
          "Date: " + cTime + " GMT\r\n"
          "Connection: close\r\n"
          "\r\n"
          "AUTHORIZED";
```

The problem is the phones don't accept that response and return `<CiscoIPPhoneError Number="4" />`.

I used node.js for that before and simply wrote "AUTHORIZED" to http.serverResponse object, but I'm confused now why it doesn't work with Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved that. 
The problem was the "Secure Authentication URL" field was set along with "Authentication url". And what I thought to be GET from phone was "Client hello"...
Cleared "Secure Authentication URL" in CUCM and it works now